# how does systemverilog argument passing value work?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

Now I'm analyzing the UVM code as below for studying.

```
 // UVM run_phase()
task run_phase(uvm_phase phase);
  forever begin
    // send the item to the DUT
    send_to_dut(req);
  end
endtask : run_phase

task send_to_dut(uart_frame frame);
  
    
endtask : send_to_dut
```

[image]

But I'm confused that how `send_to_dut(req)`'s req argument can pass to the `send_to_dut(uart_frame frame)`'s  `uart_frame frame`? It's quite confusing.

> req --> uart_frame frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because the *value* in this case is a class *handle*. And a handle is a reference to a class object. So you are passing a reference by value. See [this link](http://go.mentor.com/class-on-classes) for more details